# Get access to Wordpress when logged out

Tags: wordpress, plugins, bbpress

I have a WP site with bbPress installed and bbPress Like Button (a like button plugin).

I was trying to import a phpBB forum to bbPress.

I'm having problems doing this and in the process must have decactivted bbPress.

Now when I try to log in at wp-admin or view the site I get a page saying.

'bbPress Like Button needs bbPress installed and activated in order to work.'

This is on QA server and so I can't get access to the files.

Is there any way to fix this - Is there any way to access the dashboard to re-activate the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** If you need to deactivate the plugin, access the web server's file system (using FTP, SFTP, NFS, whatever your host has you set up with) and navigate to the `wp-content/plugins` directory of your site that is currently experiencing issues. Find the plugin that is causing the error, and rename its folder, adding a `+` in front of it. So, since the bbPress Like Button is the issue, you'd rename `bbpress-like-button` to `+bbpress_like_button`. That will deactivate the plugin and allow you to log back into the admin. You will have to remove the `+` to reactivate the plugin, once you fix the current issue.

**Solution 2:** After you've attempted to login, try going to the following URL (replacing the example.com with your domain): http://www.example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?action=deactivate&plugin=bbpress-like-button%2Fbbpress-like.php&plugin_status=all&paged=1&s&_wpnonce=3717279d91

**Solution 3:** Login to your WordPress database using phpMyAdmin, navigate to the wp_options table. Locate the option name “active_plugins” and change the value of that option to: `a:0:{}`